# React Router: When I enter "/signup" into my URL bar it redirects me to "/", but links to "/signup" work correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I tested this on my localhost as well as on a staging version on Heroku, and when I enter www.mydomain.com/signup it redirects me to www.mydomain.com/ but if I click on the link from the home page to /signup, it works.

My routing code:

```
export const Routing = () => {
  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={AuthWrapper} />
        <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
        <Route path="/how-it-works" component={HowItWorksPage} />
        <Route path="/signup" render={props => (
          <AuthPage authType="signup" {...props} />
        )} />
        <Route path="/login" render={props => (
          <AuthPage authType="login" {...props} />
        )} />
      </Switch>
          )
};

export default Routing;
```

AuthWrapper:

```
import { useAuth } from '../hooks/useAuth';

const AuthWrapper = (props) => {
  return useAuth() ? <App /> : <LandingPage />
}

export default AuthWrapper;
```

AuthPage:

```
import { Grid, Cell } from "styled-css-grid";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import AuthContainer from "../containers/AuthContainer";

const Background = styled.div`
  background-image: url('myimageurl');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 91vh;
`

const AuthPage = (props) => (
  <Background>
    <Grid
      columns={"1fr 656px 432px 1fr"}
      rows={"102px 450px 1fr"}
      areas={[
        ". . . .",
        ". authForm aside .",
        ". . . ."
      ]}
    >
      <Cell area="authForm">
        <AuthContainer {...props} />
      </Cell>
      <Cell area="aside">
        <div style={{border: "1px solid black", height: "450px"}}></div>
      </Cell>
    </Grid>
  </Background>
)

export default AuthPage;
```

useAuth() custom hook:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import useReactRouter from 'use-react-router';

const mapState = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.currentUser.isAuthenticated
});

export const useAuth = () => {

  const { history } = useReactRouter();
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector(mapState);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        history.push("/");
      }
    },
    [isAuthenticated]
  );
  return isAuthenticated;
};
```

I am not sure why the above hook would be called when the exact path of "/" is not matched in the router.

Comment: Have you tried using tthe exact prop in the Route:

<Route exact path="/signup" render={ // Your render }/>

Comment: I just tested that and it didn't work :/ Also, from my reading of the React Router documentation, I shouldn't need it. It's not just /signup that is redirecting to the root, it's every other route as well (/about, /login, etc)

Comment: What about your AuthWrapper and AuthPage components ?whats inside them?

Comment: Also post your `AuthPage` component.

Comment: Updated with additional component code

Comment: I think that the issue could be in your hook, can you update your post with the useAuth hook?

Comment: Sure thing -- updated! But why would the hook even be getting called if that route isn't matched exactly?

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez Is this an issue with the server running my React app not knowing anything about the /signup route for example, and defaulting back to "/"? I would think that if it defaulted to index.html though that it would still be able to render /signup since it's a descendant.